# How to upload data to firebase from a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to retrieve data from tableview cell by clicking each row and then upload current index of tabview cell to Firebase. However, once I click tableview the error:`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value was happened`

I get all data for the current row in tableview  cell. And I used 
`ref.child("Student").child("EnrolledSubject").setvalue()` to upload data.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
    {
            if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark {
                createEnrollAlert(title: "Withdrall Sucessfully", message: "without academic and financial penalty is permissible up until the census date for the current teaching period and can be done in this App. After census date you will need to apply for subject withdrawal.")
                tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
            }
            else{
                createEnrollAlert(title: "EnrollSucessfully", message: "without academic and financial penalty is permissible up until the census date for the current teaching period and can be done in this App. After census date you will need to apply for subject withdrawal.")
                tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
                print(indexPath.row)

                let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subjectCell", for:
                    indexPath)
                let currentTeacher = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
                let currentIdLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
                let currentSubjectName = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
                currentTeacher.text = mySubjectList[indexPath.row].teacherID
                currentIdLabel.text = mySubjectList[indexPath.row].subjectID
                currentSubjectName.text = mySubjectList[indexPath.row].subjectName
                print(currentIdLabel.text!)
                print( currentSubjectName.text!)
                let enrolledSubjectNumber = "Enrolled" + String(indexPath.row);
                let enrolledSubjects = [
                    "subjectName": currentSubjectName,
                    "subjectID":currentIdLabel,
                    "teacherID": currentTeacher
                ]
                print(currentIdLabel.text!)
                print( currentSubjectName.text!)
                print(enrolledSubjects)
                print(enrolledSubjectNumber)

                let id = String (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "LoginID"));
                //let type = String (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "LoginType"));

             ref.child("Student").child(id).child("EnrolledSubject").child(enrolledSubjectNumber).setValue(enrolledSubjects)
       }
   }

        func createEnrollAlert(title:String, message:String){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) in
                print("Yes")
            }))

            self.present(alert, animated:true, completion: nil)
       }
```

As long as I click table view the error message will be showed error: `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value was happened`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried debugging, add an exception breakpoint Xcode->Debug->Breakpoints->Create Exception Breakpoint..

Also I noticed this:

```
let enrolledSubjects = [
            "subjectName": currentSubjectName,
            "subjectID":currentIdLabel,
            "teacherID": currentTeacher
        ]
```

Here you are passing labels, you should be passing

```
let enrolledSubjects = [
            "subjectName": mySubjectList[indexPath.row].subjectName,
            "subjectID":mySubjectList[indexPath.row].subjectID,
            "teacherID": mySubjectList[indexPath.row].teacherID
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping, the reason why the project gonna be crash because my teammates put wrong Firebase bundle ID.........